# Getting Highest High and Lowest Low within the last 24 hours

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, expert-advisor

I'm trying to build a function in MQL4 for an Expert Advisor to get the highest high and the lowest low within a specific time frame, but the function I'm creating isn't working. I'm getting data returned, however it's not reporting the true highest high and the lowest low within the time frame. Here is the code:

```
  void FindHighLowWithinTimeFrame(int FunctStartHour, int FunctEndHour, double& FunctHighestHigh, double& FunctLowestLow)
  {
    int period = Period(); // Get the current chart's period in minutes
    int MinutesInDay = 24 * 60; // Total minutes in a day
    
    int BarsInDay = MinutesInDay / period; // Number of bars in a trading day for the current chart's time frame
    // int BarsInDay = 24 * 60 / period; // Number of bars in a trading day

    datetime currentTime = Time[0];
    datetime startTime = Time[BarsInDay]; // Start time for the past 24 hours
    datetime endTime = Time[0]; // End time (current time)
    
    // Convert user-defined start and end hours to a time within the last 24 hours
    datetime startWithin24Hours = Time[BarsInDay] + FunctStartHour * 3600;
    datetime endWithin24Hours = Time[BarsInDay] + FunctEndHour * 3600;

    int StartBar = iBarShift(Symbol(), period, startTime);
    int EndBar = iBarShift(Symbol(), period, endTime);

    // Ensure StartBar and EndBar are within valid range
    if (StartBar < 0) StartBar = 0;
    if (EndBar >= Bars) EndBar = Bars - 1;

    double TempHighestHigh = High[StartBar]; // Initialize with the high of the first bar
    double TempLowestLow = Low[StartBar]; // Initialize with the low of the first bar

    for (int i = StartBar + 1; i <= EndBar; i++)
    {
      if (Time[i] >= startWithin24Hours && Time[i] <= endWithin24Hours)
      {
        if (High[i] > TempHighestHigh)
          TempHighestHigh = High[i];

        if (Low[i] < TempLowestLow)
          TempLowestLow = Low[i];
      }
    }
    
    FunctHighestHigh = TempHighestHigh; // Update the output parameters with the highest high and lowest low
    FunctLowestLow = TempLowestLow;
  }
```

The idea is I want to get the highest high and the lowest low from each Forex session frame within the last 24 hours.

I've tried using the iHighest and iLowest functions, but I couldn't get those to work either. I can't tell from which bar the highest high and lowest low are coming from, and I've tried to add print/comment statements to identify the bar, but I have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

I recognize this.

Probably the error is in the assumption that a trading day has 24*60 M1 bars.
Most markets are closed during one or two hours (don't ask me why) which makes such linear synchronized calculation between minutes and bars tricky.

Eliminate the time component and continue just in bars. Might look overwhelming, but it is doable.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that.... I think my broker stops trades for 1 hour, which is the first hour in the trading day. So it might be a better approach to reset the values at new day, or perhaps store previous day in a separate variable and the current day's value in another? I'll have to think on this one.